# js submit without value

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

When I submit the form with JS. No value can be found. 

This is my Code:

```
<!-- Form file --> 

<form id="postnotes" name="postnotes" action="./mechanic/comments.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="comments" class="comments" rows="4" name="comment" cols="50" placeholder="Make a note"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('textarea#comments').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if (e.which == 27 && ! e.shiftKey) {

        document.getElementById("postnotes").submit();
       }
   });
  });
 </script>
 <!-- file comments -->
 <?php if(isset($_POST['postnotes'])){
  echo 'hello its me your looking for';

 }
  else{echo 'nope srry';}

 ?>
```

Can somebody please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're submitting when they press... `Esc`?!

Comment: yes, needed for a dashboard project. So 'enter' isn't a good choice.

Comment: *"So 'enter' is a good choice."* `Enter` != `Esc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The submit is fine, although it seems odd to submit when the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It's the PHP checking for a submission that's incorrect. You're looking for a field using the name of the *form* (`postnames`). It's the name of the *field* that gets sent (`comment`, the `name` of the `textarea`), e.g. look in `$_POST["comment"]`, not `$_POST["postnames"]`.

Comment: Tnx, need a key to save notes in a dashboard project. And because enter isn't a good choice for a textarea. i chose esc. but it's just temporarily, just want to make a key post something.